# JQuery data attribute sometimes is an array, sometimes a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting a bit of issues trying to hide arrays containing strings with special characters in checkboxes values. I've got these 3 DOM elements :

```
<div class="question-container form-group" data-id="235" data-parent-elements-visibility="[&quot;Choice 3 $^%&amp;&amp;_++_<>&quot;, &quot;Choix deux, avec des virgules et des \&quot;quotes\&quot;&quot;, &quot;Choix trois avec des a'postrop`hes et de deux &nbsp;[trucs] chelou<<.&quot;]" data-parent-id="304" id="question-container-235">
   
</div>
<div class="question-container form-group" data-id="307" data-parent-elements-visibility="[&quot;Choie 2 @\#$%^&amp;*(&quot;, &quot;Choice 3 $^%&amp;&amp;_++_<>&quot;, &quot;Choix deux, avec des virgules et des \&quot;quotes\&quot;&quot;, &quot;Choix trois avec des a'postrop`hes et de deux &nbsp;[trucs] chelou<<.&quot;]" data-parent-id="304" id="question-container-307">
   
</div>
<div class="question-container form-group" data-id="303" data-parent-elements-visibility="[&quot;Choie 2 @\#$%^&amp;*(&quot;, &quot;Choice 3 $^%&amp;&amp;_++_<>&quot;, &quot;Choix 1 mon pote ! Avec des accent est des ç cédille&quot;, &quot;Choix trois avec des a'postrop`hes et de deux &nbsp;[trucs] chelou<<.&quot;]" data-parent-id="304" id="question-container-303">
</div>
```

When I try to get the data attribute 'data-parents-elements-visibility', this is what I get :

```
$("#question-container-303").data('parent-elements-visibility')
"[\"Choie 2 @\\#$%^&*(\", \"Choice 3 $^%&&_++_<>\", \"Choix 1 mon pote ! Avec des accent est des ç cédille\", \"Choix trois avec des a'postrop`hes et de deux  [trucs] chelou<<.\"]"
$("#question-container-307").data('parent-elements-visibility')
"[\"Choie 2 @\\#$%^&*(\", \"Choice 3 $^%&&_++_<>\", \"Choix deux, avec des virgules et des \\\"quotes\\\"\", \"Choix trois avec des a'postrop`hes et de deux  [trucs] chelou<<.\"]"
$("#question-container-235").data('parent-elements-visibility')
(3) ["Choice 3 $^%&&_++_<>", "Choix deux, avec des virgules et des \"quotes\"", "Choix trois avec des a'postrop`hes et de deux  [trucs] chelou<<."]
```

So `question-container-235` behaves correctly and gives me an array back. Do you know why the other 2 are returning strings instead of the array ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: obviously theres sth wrong with the escaping, how do you produce/render the values in data-parent-elements-visibility attribute ?

Comment: Storing strings in HTML so complex that they need escaping and HTML entities and then used as an array?  That's a huge anti-pattern. Stop this insanity and keep values in HTML simple then build upon those in JS/jQ.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is data-parent-elements-visibility value in 307 has an issue with the 16th character which is a backslash. This is breaking content in between and avoid it being parse as an array.

Below will work fine(either double \ or none):

```
<div class="question-container form-group" data-id="307" data-parent-elements-visibility="[&quot;Choie 2 @\\#$%^&amp;*(&quot;, &quot;Choice 3 $^%&amp;&amp;_++_<>&quot;, &quot;Choix deux, avec des virgules et des \&quot;quotes\&quot;&quot;, &quot;Choix trois avec des a'postrop`hes et de deux &nbsp;[trucs] chelou<<.&quot;]" data-parent-id="304" id="question-container-307">
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way to handle it was what @zer00ne said : I reworked the entire thing to make an extra API call and have a nice json object to work with instead of storing that much stuff (user provided) in data attributes, which is prone to issues even if that backslash change might work in this particular case.

Thanks a lot !